# File Reading Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am making a simple game with a save and load. So far, I have the save game working and it saves all the objects positions to a .dat file. Each line has 3 coordinates (x, y, z) split by a colon. Example:

> 23.762622833251953:3.887784719467163
>   22.5:0.5:18.5
>   23.5:0.5:20.5
>   26.5:0.5:5.5
>   28.5:0.5:21.5
>   30.5:0.5:4.5
>   33.5:0.5:19.5
>   35.5:0.5:4.5
>   38.5:0.5:15.5
>   39.5:0.5:3.5
>   41.5:0.5:9.5

The very first line is coordinates to the first-person view of the player. This is easy enough to implement since I pass each coordinate into an array, so the x-position is the first element [0] and the z coordinate is the second element [1]. The y coordinate is always the same, even for blocks, so I didn't bother saving it, but I did for the blocks for some reason.

Here is the method to save a game:

```
public void saveGame()
{
    File file = new File("quickSave.dat");

    try {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);        
        writer.write(env.getCameraX()+":"+env.getCameraZ()+"\n");
        for (int row = 0; row < map.length; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < map[row].length; col++)
            {
                if (map[row][col] != null) {
                    EnvObject block = map[row][col];
                    writer.write(block.getX()+":"+block.getY()+":"+block.getZ()+"\n");
                }
            }
        }
        writer.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Game saved");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

The problem is reading each line from the file and then passing those coordinates into the object. I only implemented passing coordinates into the players perspective, which was easy because I was working with only 2 elements.

I was thinking of making another array with 2 dimensions (taking out the y-coordinate, the middle one), and each element is one line from the file, but how do I do this? Or is this another, more elegant way?

Here is my load game method so far:

```
public void loadGame() {
    File file = new File("quickSave.dat");
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        String[] elements = line.split(":");
        env.setCameraXYZ(new Float(elements[0]), 0.5,
            new Float(elements[1]));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Game loaded");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you make the *question* clear? This is a story, not a question.

Comment: Do you really need to save them as plaintext?

Comment: Hmmm... each line in the file is a pair of coordinates. I want to pass each line of coordinates into an object that gives it a position in a 3D environment. How do I do this?

Comment: Are you _specifically_ asking about the math involved, the pragmatic representation of these objects, parsing the input, or something else entirely?

Comment: The user doesn't know what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

`BufferedReader.readLine()` will help you. You'll need to split the read-in line with `String.split()`, and the convert each returned string into a float with `Float.parseFloat()` or `new Float(someString)`.

I think that's what you're asking anyway

```
String line = null;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
{
    String[] coords = line.split(":");
    EnvObject block = new EnvObject(Float.parseFloat(coords[0],
                                    Float.parseFloat(coords[1],
                                    Float.parseFloat(coords[2]
                                    );
    someArray.add(block);
}
```

Comment: I do that with the player's coordinates and it works fine. The problem is reading through 0-whatever lines and grabbing the coordinates on each line, which I then pass into an object for it's position in a 3D space.

Comment: @bobby williams but why isnt elements[0], elements[1] and elements[2] not working? this should contain the three coordinates

Comment: They do work. I use the first 2 elements for the player's position. I also save these blocks that the player can put at random throughout the environment, which is what all the other lines are below the very first one. I can't just put "add block with x-coordinate as element 2, and z-coordinate as element 3" there could be 20 blocks, 50 blocks, or however many the player places.

Comment: @bobby williams. Ok sorry I still don't understand the problem.

Comment: @James - how do I start at the second line then?

Comment: Read the first line and ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

How about using serialization? Store your state variables into an `ObjectOutputStream` and load them from an `ObjectInputStream`. Let the JVM handle all this low level bookkeeping for you, unless you really do need a format that is human-readable and editable.